# Testing react-intl components with enzyme

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme, react-intl

I have looked into react-intl for suggestions but it doesn't leave any explicit documentation for [enzyme](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Testing-with-React-Intl#enzyme).

This is how I have been trying to write my tests.

```
import {IntlProvider} from 'react-intl';

const intlProvider = new IntlProvider({locale: 'en'}, {});
const intl = intlProvider.getChildContext();
const customMessage = shallow(<CustomMessage />, { options: { context: intl } });
```

But I keep getting the error

> Invariant Violation: [React Intl] Could not find required `intl` object.  needs to exist in the component ancestry.

I looked into their repo and they seems to have [made it work](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/blob/master/test/unit/components/date.js#L109-L129) with 'react-addons-test-utils'.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've posted an answer to a similar question:

[Injecting react-intl object into mounted Enzyme components for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021217/injecting-react-intl-object-into-mounted-enzyme-components-for-testing/37023108#37023108)

You would be able to `import { shallowWithIntl } from 'intl-helper'` and then use `shallowWithIntl()` instead of Enzyme's `shallow()`.

Comment: Does anyone have those helpers like `shallowWithIntl` or `mountWithIntl` in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by using

```
const customMessage = shallow(<CustomMessage />, { context: intl });
```

instead.

Comment: That is a good approach for `shallow` instantiations. Note this won't work when using Enzyme's `mount` method.

Answer (score 0):

Thats how I achieve the things:

```js
import React from 'react';
import StandardFilterIntl, {StandardFilter} from 'bundles/components/Filter/StandardFilter';
import {mountWithIntl} from 'enzyme-react-intl';

const FilterComponent = mountWithIntl(<StandardFilterIntl {...standardFilterProps} />);
FilterComponent.find(StandardFilter).state()
```