# Injecting react-intl object into mounted Enzyme components for testing

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, react-intl

**EDIT:** Solved! Scroll down for the answer

---

In our Component tests we need them to have access to the [`react-intl`](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl) context. The problem is that we are mounting single components (with Enzyme's [`mount()`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md)) without their `<IntlProvider />` parent wrapper. This is solved by wrapping the provider around but then the `root` points to the `IntlProvider` instance and not to `CustomComponent`.

The [Testing with React-Intl: Enzyme](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Testing-with-React-Intl#enzyme) docs are still empty.

**<CustomComponent />**

```
class CustomComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    foo: 'bar'
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FormattedMessage id="world.hello" defaultMessage="Hello World!" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Standard Test Case (Desired)** (Enzyme + Mocha + Chai)

```
// This is how we mount components normally with Enzyme
const wrapper = mount(
  <CustomComponent
    params={params}
  />
);

expect( wrapper.state('foo') ).to.equal('bar');
```

However, since our component uses `FormattedMessage` as part of the `react-intl` library, we get this error when running the above code:

`` Uncaught Invariant Violation: [React Intl] Could not find required `intl` object. <IntlProvider> needs to exist in the component ancestry. ``

---

**Wrapping it with `IntlProvider`**

```
const wrapper = mount(
  <IntlProvider locale="en">
    <CustomComponent
      params={params}
    />
  </IntlProvider>
);
```

This provides `CustomComponent` with the `intl` context it asks for. However, when trying to do test assertions such as these:

```
expect( wrapper.state('foo') ).to.equal('bar');
```

raises the following exception:

`AssertionError: expected undefined to equal ''`

This ofcourse because it tries to read the state of `IntlProvider` and not our `CustomComponent`.

---

### Attempts to access `CustomComponent`

I have tried the below to no avail:

```
const wrapper = mount(
  <IntlProvider locale="en">
    <CustomComponent
      params={params}
    />
  </IntlProvider>
);


// Below cases have all individually been tried to call `.state('foo')` on:
// expect( component.state('foo') ).to.equal('bar');

const component = wrapper.childAt(0); 
> Error: ReactWrapper::state() can only be called on the root

const component = wrapper.children();
> Error: ReactWrapper::state() can only be called on the root

const component = wrapper.children();
component.root = component;
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getInstance' of null
```

---

The question is: **How can we mount `CustomComponent` with the `intl` context while still being able to perform "root" operations on our `CustomComponent`**?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have created a helper functions to patch the existing Enzyme `mount()` and `shallow()` function. We are now using these helper methods in all our tests where we use React Intl components.

You can find the gist here: https://gist.github.com/mirague/c05f4da0d781a9b339b501f1d5d33c37

---

For the sake of keeping data accessible, here's the code in a nutshell:

**helpers/intl-test.js**

```
/**
 * Components using the react-intl module require access to the intl context.
 * This is not available when mounting single components in Enzyme.
 * These helper functions aim to address that and wrap a valid,
 * English-locale intl context around them.
 */

import React from 'react';
import { IntlProvider, intlShape } from 'react-intl';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';

const messages = require('../locales/en'); // en.json
const intlProvider = new IntlProvider({ locale: 'en', messages }, {});
const { intl } = intlProvider.getChildContext();

/**
 * When using React-Intl `injectIntl` on components, props.intl is required.
 */
function nodeWithIntlProp(node) {
  return React.cloneElement(node, { intl });
}

export default {
  shallowWithIntl(node) {
    return shallow(nodeWithIntlProp(node), { context: { intl } });
  },

  mountWithIntl(node) {
    return mount(nodeWithIntlProp(node), {
      context: { intl },
      childContextTypes: { intl: intlShape }
    });
  }
};
```

**CustomComponent**

```
class CustomComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    foo: 'bar'
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FormattedMessage id="world.hello" defaultMessage="Hello World!" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**CustomComponentTest.js**

```
import { mountWithIntl } from 'helpers/intl-test';

const wrapper = mountWithIntl(
  <CustomComponent />
);

expect(wrapper.state('foo')).to.equal('bar'); // OK
expect(wrapper.text()).to.equal('Hello World!'); // OK
```

Comment: Using your helper above, I am getting `TypeError: (0 , _intl.mountWithIntl) is not a function` when trying to import mountWithIntl

Comment: Interesting, are you sure the reference to the `intl-test.js` helper file is correct? It seems to me the `import` is failing. Perhaps your `require()` set-up does not look for `.js` files by default? You could try to add the `.js` extension to your import file.

Comment: I tried adding that and same error. What is your babel setup?

Comment: Got it! https://gist.github.com/mirague/c05f4da0d781a9b339b501f1d5d33c37#gistcomment-1771277

Comment: Opted to go with your original helpers so that I could evaluate state of child components - that is an awesome feature. However, I'm now stuck on one final snag: looking up translations once the component is mounted https://gist.github.com/mirague/c05f4da0d781a9b339b501f1d5d33c37#gistcomment-1771847

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it has helped me greatly.  However, I now find myself needing to test with a locale other than 'en'.  Changing the locale in the instantiation of IntlProvider doesn't quite do the job.  For example, instantiate with a locale of 'fr' and try using formatNumber - a period is still used as a decimal separator rather than a comma.  How can I ensure that IntlProvider also loads the required locale?

Comment: if reference is right, all functions are coming in one export ypu can separate exports of helper file and then it worked for me !